# Override '+' in smalltalk, to accept two parameters?

Tags: smalltalk

Is it possible to override the + operator in smalltalk to accept two params? i.e., I need to also pass in the units for my custom class. Something like:

```
Number subclass: #NumberWithUnits
instanceVariableNames: 'myName unitTracker'
classVariableNames: ''
poolDictionaries: ''
category: 'hw3'


+ aNumber theUnits
    unitTracker adjustUnits: theUnits.
    ^super + aNumber
```

Or is there an easier way to do this that I haven't considered?

---

Additional problem description:

> **(NumberWithUnits value: 3 unit: #seconds)** should give you a **NumberWithUnits** that represents 3 seconds. But you should also be able to write 3 sec and that should evaluate to a **NumberWithUnits** (seconds is already taken in Pharo 2.0). The way to do this is to add a sec method to Number, which basically returns **(NumberWithUnits value: self unit: #seconds)**. You can add methods for meters and elephants as well. Then you could write an expression **3 elephants / (1 sec sec)** and it would return the right thing. Write a test for it to be sure!

Comment: So you want to do operations like "2 meters plus 3 feet"?

Comment: Yes - or even 2 hours + 3 elephants

Comment: And in that case you want an error that they're incommensurable?

Comment: Yes, for addition/subtraction at least. Multiplication/Division is acceptable though.

Comment: By the way, **[if you're going to ask for help with your homework, please make that clear in the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/150826)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a more idiomatic way to do this would be to construct a second `NumberWithUnits`, and then add that.

Then inside your `+` method you need to reconcile the units of the two things being added, then add their magnitudes.

So something like

```
a := Measure new: 2 #m
b := Measure new: 10 #mm

a + b

Measure class [

    + other [
        "TODO: check/convert units here"
        resultMagnitude := (a magnitude) + (b magnitude).
        combinedUnits := (a units) * (b units).
        ^Measure new resultMagnitude units: combinedUnits.
    ]

]
```

See also for example [the GNU Smalltalk example of operator overloading](http://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual/html_node/New-kinds-of-Numbers.html#New-kinds-of-Numbers).

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Unfortunately, our hw description specifies that we have to use two separate classes - a NumberWithUnits and a UnitsTracker.

Comment: What is a `UnitsTracker`?  (What an awful name.)  If there is an instance of this for eg "Elephant" or "Kilogram" then you can just have the `NumberWithUnits` hold a reference to an instance.

Comment: Yeah, awful name.  Having not seen the homework, the only thing I can think is maybe it's supposed to be a class that you can use to add units dynamically?  Something like `UnitsTracker defineUnit: #feet as: 12 units: #inches`, which would then register the forward and reverse conversions.

Comment: Yeah so UnitsTracker is basically an instanced-dictionary that holds units. The unit is the key, and the value is the associated power. This discussion may shed some light:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035060/smalltalk-dictionary-as-calculator

Comment: Aha, no conversions necessary, it seems, it just accumulates units.  The question you referenced gives a pretty good idea of how to implement it.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe I can just write static methods to handle specific units. This is also from the problem description, which may make it easier to implement than I had planned (added to original post).

Comment: OK, that question helps make it clearer, but still, the `NumberWithUnits` (also a bad name) ought to refer to the `UnitTracker` which contains the product of all units applied.

Comment: @ctote I don't see where you would want static methods here.  Things like `3 sec` are a message sent to the integer `3`.

Comment: The only other option I can think would be to implement Number>>doesNotUnderstand: to turn any unary message into a unit, but I seriously doubt that was intended.

Answer (score 5):

What you're missing is the order of evaluation/precedence in Smalltalk.  It's actually quite a bit simpler than in most other languages:

1. explicit parentheses `()`
2. unary
3. binary
4. keyword
5. assignment `:=`

So, you can implement a unary method on `Number` which gets evaluated before the binary `+`. A simple example is `Number>>negated`, which is Smalltalk's version of the unary minus.

At least in Squeak/Pharo (all I've got handy at the moment), date arithmetic is already implemented similarly.  Look at `Number>>minutes`, for example, so you can evaluate things like `5 hours - 3 minutes`, which returns a `Duration` of `0:04:57:00`.

Comment: Hm, so could you give me an example of when negated would be called during arithmetic? And maybe how I could define something similar?

Comment: Since `+` is a binary message and `negated` is a unary one, it'd be  called before the +.  Just look at how date arithmetic works, it's exactly what you want.  `Duration` is the equivalent of your `NumberWithUnits`, and I guess they're asking you to implement another class to perform the actual calculations, whereas `Duration` itself handles this.

Comment: I don't see how precedence or order of evaluation is relevant here.

Comment: Precedence is very important here: if binary operators bound more tightly than unary operators, then `5 hours - 3 minutes` would parse as `((5 hours) - 3) minutes`, rather than the desired `((5 hours) - (3 minutes))`.

Comment: So your point really is that the OP shouldn't look at `a + 3 sec` as `a.add(3, sec)` (to use java-ish syntax) but rather as `a.add(3.sec())` which is how Smalltalk will interpret it anyhow.  And from there it flows in to my answer that by the time you get to `+` the units should already be incorporated into the `NumberWithUnits`.